# Google chrome api javascript detect file open in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-app-developer-tool

For google chrome extension i need to be able to detect if user use chrome browse to open .html file.

I tried different method but it seem i do not get an event

```
"permissions": ["webRequest","browsingData", "fileSystemProvider"],
  "file_system_provider_capabilities": {
       "configurable": true,
       "watchable": true,
       "source": "file"
},
```

I tried to intercept in webRequest

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(info){
// info.url does not give me the file.html which opened


)};
```

I tried with different methods for file event handling but none get fire

```
    chrome.fileSystemProvider.onOpenFileRequested.addListener(function(file){
    console.log("open file");
});
chrome.fileSystemProvider.onReadFileRequested.addListener(function(file){
    console.log("read file");
});
chrome.fileSystemProvider.onExecuteActionRequested.addListener(function(){
    console.log("execute file");
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener. The webRequest is for web requests, obviously, and fileSystemProvider is to provide virtual file systems.

Comment: I do get an event for tabs.onUpdated but i can't see the file name.  The idea is when user open html file from local i should be able to detect and scan the content.

Comment: A tab URL is the file name so there should be no problem seeing it if you have `"permissions": ["<all_urls>"]` in manifest.json (or `file://*`). The documentation should have examples.

Comment: thank you much for your comment, it did give me some hint.  What i have right now for permission is "*://*/"  how ever it is not enough I also need to include "file://*" .   So now I am be able to capture file protocol in  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much thank you for wOxxOm to give me a hint.  What I currently have in my permission is "*://*/".  I need to include "file://*" in the permission. I thought the *: should be good enough but not in this case.   So right now I am be able to see file:// protocol in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Comment: I tried out the suggested technique I didn't succeeded. I see a lot of requests which the page does - .js and .css files, but not the .html as such, not the first request. Can you write the code which intercepts the request to a local file when it's opened via the browser, please?

Comment: I was using Firefox and it turned out that Firefox doesn't fire the event when a local file is opened, but Opera (and probably Chrome too) does. By the way, Firefox fires onBeforeNavigate event when a local file is opened, while Opera doesn't.